# Why does this AT&T assembly code give a segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, x86, scanf, coredump, gnu-assembler

This is my first assembly source code, I want to use `scanf` function but this ELF gives a segmentation fault.

So, I tried to solve using core dump, but I couldn't.

## using scanf function

```
.section .data
 
string: 
.ascii "input yournumber : \0"
 
value: 
.ascii "your value is %d \n\0"

scanf:
.ascii "%d"

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:

movl %esp, %ebp
subl $4, %esp

pushl $string
call printf

leal -4(%ebp), %ebx
pushl %ebx
pushl $scanf
call scanf

pushl -4(%ebp)
pushl $value
call printf

pushl $0
call exit
```

Comment: How did you build and run this?  If you statically linked it, or you tried this on MinGW, then libc isn't initialized because you ran it from `_start`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Instead of looking at just the core-dump, look at how you got there by starting the executable inside `gdb`.**  Single-step instructions with `si`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more GDB tips.

You have a ton of bugs which can cause crashes, and some which *definitely* will.

---

**You define a `scanf` symbol, so `call scanf` jumps there.**

It's in the `.data` section, so the page might not be executable.

Or maybe the bytes for `"%d"` decode to x86 machine code that crashes, given those register values.

Use a different symbol name like `scanf_fmt` for the scanf format string.  Also don't forget to **use `.asciz`** to zero-terminate the implicit-length C string.

---

If you statically linked this, or you tried this on MinGW or Cygwin, then libc isn't initialized because you're defining `_start` instead of `main`.  In a dynamically-linked Linux executable, glibc uses dynamic linker hooks to get its init functions called.  Even so, **it's not recommended to use libc functions from `_start`.**

---

`printf` or `scanf` might possibly also crash because the stack is only aligned by 8 bytes, when the ABI allows it to assume 16.  The stack is aligned by 16 on entry to `_start`, but you only do 1 `push` + 1x `sub $4, %esp` before printf.

But most Linux distros don't build 32-bit code with `-msse2`, so the compiler won't use 16-byte alignment-required loads/stores to copy stuff around.  (x86-64 glibc's `scanf` does crash if called with an under-aligned stack.)

And you do actually call `scanf` with an aligned stack; a total offset of 16 from entry to `_start`, because you don't waste instructions cleaning the stack after `printf` returns.  That's a valid choice, as long as you're aware that you're doing it.  (It deserves a comment, and / or you could use `mov` instead of `push` for later args to reuse those same stack slots.)

I'd suggest looking at (optimized) compiler output for a function that does what you want.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/