# Segmentation fault (core dumped) displayed

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, max, min

I wrote a code in Assembly x86 that is supposed to find the minimum and the maximum values of a given array and print them:

```
.data
    n: .long 6
    v: .long 15, 20, 11, 8, 35, 26
    formatprint: .asciz "%d : %d"

.text

.global main

main:
    lea v, %edi
    mov $0, %ecx
    mov (%edi, %ecx, 4), %eax
    mov (%edi, %ecx, 4), %ebx
    inc %ecx 
    
    for_elem_v:
        cmp n, %ecx
        je Print
        
        mov (%edi, %ecx, 4), %edx
        cmp %edx, %eax
        jl maximum
        
        cmp %edx, %ebx
        jg minimum
        
        maximum:
            mov %edx, %eax
            jmp incrementation
        
        minimum:
            mov %edx, %ebx
            jmp incrementation
        
        incrementation:
            inc %ecx
            jmp for_elem_v
            
Print:
    push %ebx
    push %eax
    push $formatprint
    call printf
    pop %ecx
    pop %ecx
    pop %ecx

    push $0
    call fflush
    pop %ecx


exit:
    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

The problem is that it displays "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I try to run it. Can you help me solve it?
[image]

Comment: Which instruction faults when you run it under `gdb ./ex4`?  Oh, you `call formatprint`, but that's a string in `.data` (non-executable, and not machine code anyway).  You have to actually call the `printf` function with that as an arg, not point EIP at your ASCII data!

Comment: The actual problem is a duplicate of [Why does this AT&T assembly code give a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51742348) but that was an accident of defining the format string with the same name as the function.  For how to use printf, [Outputting variable values in x86 asm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2504974)